# Manipulate excel with python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx

I'm having issues with an excel with a weird format [excel format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr3i0.png), I was looking to put them in a suitable format with python pandas since right now they are separated by days, and it should be all followed like this [suitable format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMHNv.png).
When I read it with pandas using read_excel, I want to unify them and remove the first title-date, from this:

```
Unnamed: 1
NaN NaN
04Oct2020 (Sunday)  NaN
date & time         cars
04/10/2020 00:00:00 1
04/10/2020 00:01:00 2
```

to the suitable form something like this:

```
date & time         cars
04/10/2020 00:00:00 1
04/10/2020 00:01:00 2
.
.
05/10/2020 00:00:00 1
```

(dots are to show that the days are unified). How can I do it? I have not succeeded, any help is appreciated!

Comment: This could be done quite easily. What's the error in your current code?

Comment: @MitchellOlislagers I'm pretty new on this, I can manually remove the rows with the date and day, but imagine that instead of two of these rows I have the days of one month, I have to do it manually? Or there is a clean way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very hacky way that should work for your dataset.

```
import pandas as pd

exclude = ["Mean", "STDEV", "Median", "Min", "Max", "date & time"]
df = pd.read_excel("test.xls", names = ["date_time", "cars"])
df = df[~df.date_time.isin(exclude)].dropna()
df.to_excel("testoutput.xls", index=False)
```

Which will write this output to a new Excel file, dropping the row indices.

```
              date_time cars
1   2020-10-04 00:00:00    1
2   2020-10-04 00:01:00    2
3   2020-10-04 00:02:00    3
4   2020-10-04 00:03:00    4
5   2020-10-04 00:04:00    5
6   2020-10-04 00:05:00    6
7   2020-10-04 00:06:00    7
17  2020-10-05 00:00:00    1
18  2020-10-05 00:01:00    2
19  2020-10-05 00:02:00    3
20  2020-10-05 00:03:00    4
21  2020-10-05 00:04:00    5
22  2020-10-05 00:05:00    6
23  2020-10-05 00:06:00    7
24  2020-10-05 00:07:00    8
25  2020-10-05 00:08:00    9
26  2020-10-05 00:09:00   10
```